# C# WebBrowser not loading local Javascript file

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control

I am using the C# WebBrowser control.  My HTML renders fine.  However, I need to keep external files on the local computer.  References to the local copy of files do not work.

How do I write the HTML to load locally stored files?

This works:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js'></script>
```

This works when loading a file directly in to a browser, but not through the C# WebBrowser control:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='./jquery-latest.min.js'></script>
```

Adding the full path gets rid of error messages, but still does not work.

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='file:///C:/<full path>/jquery-latest.min.js'></script>
```

I have tried adding this to the first line of the html file which does not solve the problem.

```
<!-- saved from url=(0014)about:internet -->
```

Answer (score 1):

Just put your local js file in the same directory with your html file. Then use this will do

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='./jquery-latest.min.js'></script>
```

Comment: Ok, I tried that before and it didn't work.  Now that you posted this, it does :)  Arghhh...
Thanks!

Comment: Edited question to clarify issue.  Not so fast.  It works if I load the html file into a browser.  But if I load the html file through the C# WebBrowser control, the external file is not loaded.  It's a path issue.
I specified the full path and still not working, ie: file:///c:/...